# Dijkstra' algorithm- vertex as coordinate

Tags: c++, algorithm, dijkstra, shortest-path

I went through **Dijkstra for shortest path algorithm**,while i was practicing i encountered a question in which vertex is not a **single number**(say 1,2,3...and so)but it was a pair more specifically given as **(x,y)coordinates**.I have never done such type of question nor i have seen them.Can you please help me out how to approach for such kind of question.**O(V^2) is heartily welcome**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Map the coordinates to integer vertices using a hashmap. Now you have a graph with nodes as single numbers. Apply dijkstra's algorithm.
 Time complexity : `O(V)` for converting to integer vertices. 
`O(V^2)` for running dijkstra's algorithm. 
Therefore `O(V^2)` total complexity.

Pseudo code:

```
int cntr = 0; 
for(Edge e : graph){
    int from = e.from;
    int to= e.to;
    if(!map.contains(from)){
        map.put(from, cntr++);    
    }

    if(!map.contains(to)){
        map.put(to, cntr++);    
    }
}
```

Comment: I got it.You mean something like map<pair<int,int>,int>mp; But what value should i assign with respect to each key ?I mean it has to be unique.How can i do that ?

Comment: Just keep increasing a counter and assign it to the nodes. @chotabheem see the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Each vertex would still have an id (which you could assign, if not given). The Cartesian coordinates are just additional attributes of the vertex, which could be used to compute distances between connected vertices. (sqrt(delta_x^2 + delta_y^2))